# Injectable builder

Tags: java, cdi, builder, inject

I'd like to create builder class and use it as follows:

```
public class SomeBean {

 @Inject
 private Builder builder;

 public void method() {
    List<SomeObject> objects = ... ;
    for (SomeObject object : objects ) {

        if (someConditionSatisfy()) {
            builder.withPropertyA(object.getPropertyA);
        }
        builder.withPropertyB(object.getPropertyB);
        builder.withPropertyC(object.getPropertyC);

        BuiltObject builtObject = builder.build();

        someOutputList.add(builtObject);
    } 
 }

}
```

But in method method() I have conditional if statement:

```
if (someConditionSatisfy()) {
    builder.withPropertyA(object.getPropertyA);
}
```

Let's assume that in the first iteration of loop the condition is satisfied and *builder.withPropertyA()* method is invoked. In the second iteration the condition is not satisfied. But first iteration has already set property A in builder, so the second object created by build method of builder class includes also this property. I'd like to avoid this case. So the question is: How should I do this? Should I "reset" all builder fields in its build() method after targeted object is created? Or should I create new instance of Builder each time (but I don't know how to do this and don't use new keyword - I quess that I should obtain new builder instance from container)?

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score -1):

You must use fabric in this case, instead inject builder inject fabric that return new builder instance for every invokation. This is simplest and concise solution. Instead of reuse builder simple throw it away, it is simplify your code and unit test cases. If you processing big amount of `SomeObject` for performance reasons you maybe should reuse builder but make it fabric deal, instead creating new `Builder` change fabric code to create only one instance of `Builder` class and for every invokation of `create()` method reset builder and return this instance again. In this way you don't need to change of code of `SomeBean` class.

```
public class SomeBean {

 @Inject
 private BuilderFabric builderFabric;

 public void method() {
    List<SomeObject> objects = ... ;
    for (SomeObject object : objects ) {
        Builder builder = builderFabric.create();   
        if (someConditionSatisfy()) {
            builder.withPropertyA(object.getPropertyA);
        }
        builder.withPropertyB(object.getPropertyB);
        builder.withPropertyC(object.getPropertyC);

        BuiltObject builtObject = builder.build();

        someOutputList.add(builtObject);
    } 
 }

}

public class BuilderFabric {

    public Builder create() {
        return new Builder();
    }
}
```